# Writing an arbitrary two-cycle, say $(a,b)\in S_n$ as a product of adjacent transpositions.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to express $(a,b)$, an arbitrary transposition, as a product of adjacent transpositions. I have figured out a method for the form $(a,a+1)$ and $(a,a+2)$ but the general form has me stumped.

Comment: If you want to write (25) cut 5 squares, draw the numbers 1 to 5 on them and swapping adjacent squares only interchange the 2 and the 5: record the moves. If you do this a few times you should see a pattern.

Comment: If you can do $(a,a+1)$ and $(a,a+2)$, and you can't see the general pattern, then the next logical step is to try $(a,a+3)$. Also, see if you can describe what you're doing in broader terms than a list of transpositions: "first I do this thing, then I do that thing, and I'm done". Those are often more easily generalized.

Answer (score 1):

For $(a,b)$, with $a\lt b$, write $(b, b-1)(b-1, b-2)\cdots (a+2, a+1)(a+1, a)(a+2,a+1)\cdots(b, b-1)$

Comment: Maybe the following example is useful to ilustrate the process,
$a = 1$, $b = 4$,
$(1,4) = (4,3)(3,2)(2,1)(3,2)(4,3)$
applied to, e.g., $(1,4)[2, 1, 1, 0] = [0,1,1,2]$,
using the decomposition you get the same result:
$(4,3)[2,1,1,0] = [2,1,0,1]$,
$(3,2)[2,1,0,1] = [2,0,1,1]$,
$(1,2)[2,0,1,1] = [0,2,1,1]$,
$(3,2)[0,2,1,1] = [0,1,2,1]$,
$(4,3)[0,1,2,1] = [0,1,1,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

The conjugate of $(a,a+2)$ by $(a+2,a+3)$ is $(a,a+3)$, that is
$$(a+2,a+3)(a,a+2)(a+2,a+3)=(a,a+3)$$
so if you can express $(a,a+2)$ in terms of adjacent transpositions, you can do that for $(a,a+3)$. In general,
$$(b,b+1)(a,b)(b,b+1)=(a,b+1)$$
so if you can do $(a,b)$ then you can do $(a,b+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume many persons are standing in a line. Our aim is to make the first person in the line to go to the last position and vice versa.  We also want everyone else to be in their own position. Allowed moves are two persons standing next to each other can swap their positions.

Call the persons A,B,C,D,E in that order.

Move 1: BACDE (first two swap)

Move 2: BCADE (2nd and third swap their positions)

Move 3: BCDAE (3rd and 4th swap)

Move 4: BCDEA (4th and 5th swap)

Now let us start reverse movement

Move 6: BCEDA (3rd and 4th swap)

Move 7: BECDA (2nd and 3rd swap)

Move 8: EBCDA (first two swap)

Objective achieved.